# apply css if it has child element

Tags: html, css

In below situation I want to apply css `label` to only if it has only `canvas` element and if it is in col-sm-12.
Any help? Thanks

```css
.col-sm-12>.control-label  { /* if it has canvas */
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="s-field col-sm-12">
  <label class="control-label mb5">canvas</label>
  <canvas id="editable-image-canvas" class="icanvas" width="500" height="461"></canvas>
</div>

<div class="s-field col-sm-12">
  <label class="control-label mb5">first name</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Only css won't help here.
But if you swap the elements inside the div, the problem is solved.
And you can put the elements in place with flex-direction: column-reverse;

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  position: relative;
}

div canvas + label {
  color: red;
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
}

canvas {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid aquamarine;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <canvas></canvas>
  <label>Canvas</label>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="text" />
  <label>First name</label>
</div>
```

Comment: hi label canvas should be above the canvas. this is not working

Comment: Visually it will be above the canvas.

Comment: yes it should but its going down so I need apply css i can do  float: left; 
      position: absolute; to label if it has canvas as a child but not to other

Comment: Similarly, apply position:absolute to the label

Comment: i want to reach here  .col-sm-12 > .control-label < canvas(if there is canvas below .control-label){  }

Comment: here is the image that describe the situation https://ibb.co/7gtwQMN